# How can i redirect to a page (home) via another page(success page) where some success message is to be displayed?

Tags: php, redirect

I am using php 5+,Windows, Apache server.

I have a registration page `createaccount.php` on whose successful registration I want to show the `createaccountsuccess.php` page for few seconds only then proceeding to homepage `hompage.php` by itself..

Like this:

```
Registration Page----> Successfull Registration------> Home page
                   (Wait for 3 seconds on this page)
```

How Can I do this? please help me....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These "few second messages" are usability fault. You cannot be sure it was read. And it's annoying. Just redirect user right to the user's details page where he can learn that registration was successful and can review his settings.

Comment: @OM it become even more annoying :) Look around: nobody uses it nowadays. It's last century technology. If user have to stay on the same page, we use AJAX both to submit and inform. If user going to go to another page - just redirect them.

Answer (score 5):

Use a HTML-Meta-tag in the html-header

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=createaccountsuccess.php">
```

Comment: But this one doesn't redirect to the home page, right? The page `createaccountsuccess.php` should redirect to the home page after three seconds. This answer redirects to `createaccountsuccess.php` after three seconds... but most likely the user is already on that page.

Answer (score 4):

Place this between the `<HEAD>` and `</HEAD>` tags of your HTML code for `createaccountsuccess.php`:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="3; url=http://hompage.php">
```

The above HTML redirect code will redirect your visitors to `hompage.php` (but I think you want `homepage.php` :-) after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's setTimeout can be of help. But the better solution is one of those:

- let user stay at that intermediate page and decide to leave it on himself
- embed "success" message in the home page (use cookies for that)