# Google site, html box, 0+0 error message

Tags: html, google-sites, html-box-gadget

I am trying to run following HTML & JavaScript Code in HTML box in google sites, but running into this error, "0+0: folding element body into parent" and no success.
Any ideas?
Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.somewhere.com/" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Redirecting in 3 seconds...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Source:
[Redirect website after certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292038/redirect-in-3-sec)

Answer (score 1):

Use the "URL Redirector" gadget as instructed here: [redirect - K8OMS Help Site](http://www.k8oms.net/redirect)

> Add URL Redirector Gadget to your page.
>
> 1. Edit page
> 2. Insert
> 3. More Gadgets
> 4. Search for URL Redirector
> 5. Select it
> 6. Configure it with the URL to redirect to and the number of seconds (be sure to include the whole URL including the http://)

also, after `3. More Gadgets` be sure to click `Public` then search

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a javascript function that runs when the body loads. Use the setTimeout() function. This'll probably give you more control over your redirection as well, so you can play around with it :)

Comment: Hi Simon Have tried this one, causing the same error message
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function delayer(){
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/"
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)">
<h2>Prepare to be redirected!</h2>
<p>This page is a time delay redirect, please update your bookmarks to our new 
location!</p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Try this, might work:
`<html><head><script type="text/javascript"> function redirect{window.location = "http://www.google.com";} </script> <body onload="setTimeout('redirect()', 5000)">`
If this do not work then I am clueless, I'm using that script myself :)

Comment: I googled some on your error (never encountered it myself so do not know of it) and it seems to be a known bug within Google sites... check this thread out: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1549
My knowledge stops here, sorry I could not assist.

Comment: I was afraid the problem would lay in the html box. I guess I have to wait and see.
Thanks anyway.