# How to redirect automatically after short delay on Error 404 page?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, redirect

I have setup a custom 404 page [here](http://minimalistarray.com/404.html)

I have edited the .htaccess file for the 404 page to work.

What I want is to redirect a visitor to the home page automatically
after a short delay on the 404 page, when he clicks on a non-existing link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect website after certain amount of time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292038/redirect-website-after-certain-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a **client side redirection** method to apply the proper delay. If you want to support browsers with disabled **JavaScript**, just paste a `META refresh` into a `noscript` element. It is better to place it inside a `noscript` element because search engines give a penalty for usual `META refresh` links.

If the redirect is permanent, I suggest you to use the `canonical` tag too to keep the link-juice of missing pages.

This **[JavaScript redirect](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/) generator** is a good way to go. The code pasted from there. It also has an IE 8 and lower fix to pass the HTTP referer, which is useful for traffic analysis.

```
<!-- Pleace this snippet right after opening the head tag to make it work properly -->

<!-- This code is licensed under GNU GPL v3 -->
<!-- You are allowed to freely copy, distribute and use this code, but removing author credit is strictly prohibited -->
<!-- Generated by http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/ -->

<!-- REDIRECTING STARTS -->
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/"/>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=https://example.com/">
</noscript>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">var IE_fix=true;</script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "https://example.com/";
    var delay = "5000";
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        setTimeout(GoToURL, delay);
    }
    function GoToURL()
    {
        if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
        {
            var referLink = document.createElement("a");
            referLink.href = url;
            document.body.appendChild(referLink);
            referLink.click();
        }
        else { window.location.replace(url); } // All other browsers
    }
</script>
<!-- Credit goes to http://insider.zone/ -->
<!-- REDIRECTING ENDS -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 14):

Use meta refresh tag in 404 page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://www.example.com/404.html'" />
```

it will redirect according to content value(in seconds) and the URL where you want to redirect

Comment: This meta tag is deprecated. Following users should not use this anymore.

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element

Answer (score 3):

Just add a little PHP to your 404 error page.

I assume you have this in your `htaccess` file, `ErrorDocument 404 /error/404/`

So on `/error/404` you can do the following anywhere.

```
<?php
    header("refresh:5; url=/wherever.html"); 
?>
```

Be sure to change `5` to your seconds and `wherever.html` to your pat.

Comment: Yes I have this `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in my `.htaccess`.
I have zero knowledge in PHP. Where should I put it?
Also, the meta refresh tag has worked for me. Do I have any benefit with the php over the other one?

Comment: @SamDG It would be a good idea to use some php and learn some of it. Basically this runs wherever you put it in the file. php > html or html > php either way it still runs.