# PHP redirect after 5 seconds

Tags: php, redirect

How do I redirect page with PHP after 5 seconds to file register.php?
No Javascript or other code, just plain PHP.

Is it possible? How do I do it? I've seen Location: header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect automatically after short delay on Error 404 page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029518/how-to-redirect-automatically-after-short-delay-on-error-404-page)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use header Refresh.
It is simple:

```
header("Refresh:5; url=register.php");
```

It should work, make sure no output is before this header.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options:

1. Refresh Header

   ```
   header("Refresh:5; url=register.php");
   ```
2. Sleep then Location Header

   ```
   sleep(5);
   header("Location: register.php");
   ```

The first option is best, the `sleep` in the 2nd is blocking and could be used to DDos your service.

Answer (score 1):

```
// sleep php process
sleep(5);
// redirect
header("location: register.php");
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Comment: I would include an explanation as to where the code needs to be entered and an explanation of why this code works.