# PHP: Auto hit the submit button after limited time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Sorry, I don't know codes much.

I want to make a quiz exam were student will submit his/her answer between a limited time.

I tried to use `setTimeout();` unfortunately didn't worked for me. The page was refreshing but I didn't get anything form `echo $_POST['name'];`

My form-

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="answer" >
   <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

If the student can't finish the answer between 10 Sec, the page will stop him to type anyting and will take him to result.php where he can see the answers he gave.
result.php

```
<?php

echo $_POST['answer'];

?>
```

Hope you will solve it for me.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried using `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Maybe redirect with a meta tag?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292038/redirect-website-after-certain-amount-of-time#answer-3292056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blueblazer172's answer was correct. But give your form an id then submit or else js will submit all the forms in the page
`html`

```
<form id="anything" action="result.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="answer" >
   <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

`JS`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('form').submit();
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in jquery like:

```
setTimeout(function() {   
    //call click event after a certain time
    $('input[name="submit"]').click();
}, 10000);    // time is ms
```